# Boost timer expires immediately

Tags: c++, boost

I run boost `deadline_timer` and do `async_wait`, but timer cancelled immediately. What i am doing wrong? I run ioService in my main file.

Thank you for any possible help

```
class A(boost::asio:io_service& ioService):
m_timer(ioService) 
{ 
    m_timer.expires_at(boost::posix_time::pos_infin);
    m_timer.async_wait([this](const boost::system::error_code& ec)
     {
       std::cout << "Timer callback " << ec.message() << std::endl; 
     });
```

Comment: what is the message displayed?

Comment: Show us the code that constructs the instance!

Answer (score 2):

Check the lifetime of your `A` object.

E.g. if you do this:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A(boost::asio::io_service& ioService) : m_timer(ioService)
    {
        m_timer.expires_at(boost::posix_time::pos_infin);
        m_timer.async_wait(
            [this](const boost::system::error_code& ec) { std::cout << "Timer callback " << ec.message() << std::endl; }
        );
    }
    boost::asio::deadline_timer m_timer;
};

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service svc;
    {
        A a(svc);
    }
    svc.run();
}
```

The timer will have been canceled even before `run()` is invoked.

The following will do what you expected

```
int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service svc;
    {
        A a(svc);
        svc.run();
    } // A destructed after `run()` completes
}
```